# What would happen if you married Aela and did the mission for the Dawnguard DLC where you have to turn you spouse into a vampire?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I was wondering this because she is a werewolf and I’m a vampire.

Answer (score 3):

From [this UESP page](http://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Gift):

> This quest will not be offered if you are married to any of the following people:
>
> - Aela the Huntress

You can't turn Aela into a vampire.